# Conditional formatting columns in microsoft excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I would like a conditional format formula that would change all the cells in column G to the color green when the letters "SB" are present.

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself yet? Superuser appreciates a little effort put into things. Excel 2013 has the option to select custom filters with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells from column G, go to the Home tab, click on Conditional formatting, pick Highlight Cells Rules, Text that Contains, type SB in the left box, select Custom in the right box, go to the last tab, pick a green color you like, click OK.